# How to install programs using source code (e.g. wine staging 2.9)

Tags: software-installation, wine, playonlinux, source

Completely new to ubuntu, I am trying to install GOG Galaxy using wine and PlayOnLinux. I am having no luck so far but many people recommend using wine staging 2.8+. Using the terminal to install wine staging only got me the 2.1.6 version, but I have downloaded a .tar.gz wine staging 2.9 file (from here: https://github.com/wine-compholio/wine-staging/releases/tag/v2.9).

I tried googling it and everyone says there should be a 'config' file but when I extract it, I see nothing of the sort.

Could anyone explain to me in a noob friendly way how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Consider adding it to your http://lutris.net/ cloud library and then running it

Answer (score 2):

From https://wine-staging.com/installation.html

> Tue, 28 Mar 2017: We have updated our build servers and have
>   deprecated the repositories which were previously available at
>   repos.wine-staging.com. We recommend all users to switch to the WineHQ
>   repositories using the instructions below.

If you read down that page it has instructions for Ubuntu

> Ubuntu
>
> Start by importing the key for our repository:
>
> ```
> wget -nc https://repos.wine-staging.com/wine/Release.key
> sudo apt-key add Release.key
> ```
>
> Then use the following command to add our repository
>   to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
> ```
>
> As a next step, please update the package cache and install Wine Staging:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I followed the instructions you provided me and when I entered the final command, it said 'wine staging is already the newest version (2.16.0~xenial).

Is the 2.9 and 2.16 version the same thing?
https://github.com/wine-compholio/wine-staging/releases/tag/v2.9

Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: No it is not the same thing but you would have to contact the developers for additional instructions as that package is not in the Ubuntu repositories and the developers have not posted additional information on their web site.